# Application of algebraic geometry in studying geodesic and hypersurface

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics, algebraic-geometry

Hypersurface and geodesic can, in principle be written as function of spacetime co-ordinates but not all of them can be written as a polynomial therefore my question is: does algebraic geometry finds any usage in general relativity and if it does how?

My question arose after seeing [this](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-0721-1_17) DeWitt paper.

Answer (score 1):

*This answer was supposed to be a comment, but got too long. So it is not a full answer by any means.*

I don't know enough about this subject to give a definite answer (and right now I don't have the means to read the referred paper), but I'd suppose that using methods of algebraic geometry has more to do with algebraic geometric techniques than the algebraic geometric setting.

For example, a smooth manifold has a sheaf of commutative rings on it, namely the (sheaf of) smooth functions. From this point on, most things in differential geometry can be defined using entirely this sheaf.

For example if $C_x^\infty$ is the stalk of this sheaf at $x\in M$ (i.e. the space of germs), then tangent vectors at $x$ are derivations of $C_x^\infty$. If $\mathcal I_x$ is the ideal of $C^\infty_x$ that consists of all germs that vanish at $x$, then $\mathcal I_x/\mathcal I_x^2$ is the cotangent space at $x$, and the exterior differential $d$ is just the quotient projection, etc.

In fact I highly suspect that a smooth manifold can be defined without any reference to charts at all by demanding that it should be a Hausdorff, second countable topological space $M$ with a structure sheaf $\mathcal O_M$ of commutative rings such that for all $x\in M$, the stalk $\mathcal O_{M}(x)$ is isomorphic to the stalk $C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$. Maybe some additional constraints also need to be put on the structure sheaf, to be honest I am kinda out of my element here.

These techniques are fundamentally algebro-geometric in nature, and they have the advantage that they generalize easily and often tend to work outside the smooth category.

The smooth category itself is quite ill-behaved in that regard that it has a tendency not to contain limits and colimits. For example, the quotients of manifolds are usually not manifolds, the inductive and projective limits of a system of manifolds are usually not manifolds, the mapping spaces of manifolds are usually not manifolds (i.e. the set of smooth maps between two manifolds), the moduli spaces of differential geometric structures are usually not manifolds (for example the set of all Riemannian metrics modulo diffeomorphisms on a given manifold) , etc.

The above mentioned spaces might however exist as some kind of "generalized manifolds", like diffeological spaces or smooth spaces, etc., and those kind of structures are almost always defined via some heavy category-theoretical and algebro-geometric machinery.

It is however quite easy to see that stuff such as mapping spaces or moduli spaces are quite important to general relativity, so being able to treat them rigorously as manifold-like objects would be really nice. I *suspect* that most algebro-geometric techniques are employed to be able to do that.